# Display multiple d3 graphs in accordion-style

Tags: jquery, d3.js, accordion

I wrote a couple D3 scripts - one that generates a bar graph, the other generates an HTML table with textual content.  Ideally, I would like to display the D3-generated outputs in an accordion-like fashion where I can go back and forth between looking at the data (bar graph) and the metadata that was used to generate the data (HTML table).  jQuery has such an accordion (http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) but I don't think combining D3 and jQuery is the solution.  How would I go about that using just D3?

Comment: You would have to set/animate the heights according to which tab is active. I don't see a reason to reimplement this in D3 though.

Comment: Thanks for your respons Lars!  The original assignment was to do the D3 graphs.  Once I had them I was asked to "combine" them into an accordion.  I don't seem to be able fo find a working solution for that.  So I was wondering if other people did that and if so, how.

Comment: If I were to do it, I would simply use the jQuery UI accordion.